# Error while loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.2:

Tags: sql-server, linux

Hi i am trying to run sqlcmd in linux  by this

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '123'
```

and i get this error

```
sqlcmd: error while loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

how  can  i solve this problem -
Linux ( Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Have you installed  `libodbc`, which is part of the `unixodbc-dev` package?

Comment: i tryed to install unixodbc-dev like this  `sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev` and i get this error  `E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.`

Comment: Sounds like you've broken something, @SabZero. Though how to fix broken source files is better asked on [ubuntu.se] I would suggest remove the source list and readding it and see if that fixes it.

Comment: thank you very much If I remove source file , will it not affect the rest of the applications or the server - because I opened this file and saw information about the server contabo in it?

Comment: So have you been amending the contents of the source files, @SabZero? If you don't know what you're doing with them why are you messing around with them?

Comment: thank you @Larnu for feedback  i add new soruce files to server and solved it